# When using Cucumber with REST assured i continuously get pending exception

Tags: java, cucumber, rest-assured

**Summary**:
Iam new using Cucumber with REST assured when i try to implement this simple test which will get the nuValue from the XML response then validate that all values are more than 4000, i get some errors when try to run the test that the test skipped

**This is my feature file**

```
Feature: This Test will validate the value of numViews to be more than 4000
  Scenario: The user will be able to validate that numValue values are greater than 400

    Given The API url
    Then Validates the numValue value greater than 4000
```

**and this the step definition step file**

```
import io.cucumber.java.en.Given;
import io.cucumber.java.en.Then;
import io.restassured.RestAssured;
import io.restassured.response.Response;

import java.util.List;

public class MyStepdefs {
    Response response;
    public List<String> x;
    @Given("The API url")
    public void theAPIUrl() {
        RestAssured.baseURI=("https://www.colourlovers.com");
        String path = "/api/patterns";
        response = RestAssured
                .given()
                .header("User-Agent:", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.45 Safari/537.36")
                .get(path)
                .then().extract().response();
        List<String> numViewsList = response.xmlPath().getList("patterns.pattern.numViews");
        x = numViewsList;
    }

    @Then("Validates the numValue value greater than {int}")
    public void validatesTheNumValueValueGreaterThan() {
       for (String x : numViewsList) {
            int numViewsValue = Integer.parseInt(x);
            if (numViewsValue > 4000){
                System.out.println("Success!");
                assert(true);
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Fail!");
                assert(false);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**I get this error in the console**

```
Step undefined
You can implement this step and 1 other step(s) using the snippet(s) below:

@Given("The API url")
public void the_api_url() {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    throw new io.cucumber.java.PendingException();
}
@Then("Validates the numValue value greater than {int}")
public void validates_the_num_value_value_greater_than(Integer int1) {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    throw new io.cucumber.java.PendingException();
}
```

Comment: May be you wrongly configured your stepDefinition file location in runner file.

Comment: No iam running it from the feature file

Answer (score 0):

I guess U have not specified your glue path to step definition , which is why cucumber canot see your step def class, and it's insisting you implement the steps